# Understanding Hörmanders Theorem 1.3.3 and properties of hull

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I am reading by myself Hörmander's book *An Introduction to Complex Analysis* and I have some doubts on the paragraphs after Runge's Theorem:

Let $\Omega$ an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $K\subset\Omega$ a compact set. On page 8 of the book, 8 lines above Theorem 1.3.3. he says

> For every compact set $K\subset \Omega$ then the hull $\hat{K_{\Omega}}$ is
>   thus a compact subset of $\Omega$ containing $K$.

[image]

However, on Christine Laurent-Thiébaut's book *Holomorphic Function Theory in Several Variables* page 116 there is a remark. We have seen that $\hat{K_{\Omega}}$ is always bounded and closed in $\Omega$, but it is not in general a compact set in $\Omega$. See the print.

[image]

I understood that it is bounded and closed on $\Omega$ why it is not compact? That got me confused. Do you have some example?

And there is a part of the following theorem thah I do not understand.

**Theorem 1.3.3.** $\hat{K_{\Omega}}$ Is the union of $K$ and the components of $\Omega\setminus K$ which are relatively compact on $\Omega$.

On the proof he denotes by $K_1$ the union of $K$ and all such components. Now $\Omega\setminus K_1$ is open, since is a union of open components of $\Omega\setminus K$. Hence is $K_1$ is compact. I do not understand why $K_1$ is compact.

Than you!

Comment: "closed in $\Omega$" - that is, closed with respect to the subspace topology on $\Omega$. For example $(0,1]$ is closed with respect to $(0,\infty)$, and is bounded. But it is not compact.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for your help. I understand that, I will get it if he says: $\hat{K_{\Omega}}$ is not compact on $\mathbb{C}$. But if it is bounded and closed on $\Omega$, Why it is not compact on $\Omega$?

Comment: "Closed" is a condition on a set that depends on the topology of the ambient space. But compactness depends only on the topology on the set itself. A set is either compact or it is not. It does not matter how that set sits in some ambient space. So there is no "compact *on $\Omega$*". There is only "compact".

Comment: On the other hand, "bounded" doesn't depend on the topology, but on the metric. Two metrics can generate the same topology (and therefore the same compact sets), but differ on which sets are bounded or not. $d(x,y) = \min(1,|x - y|)$ is a metric on $\Bbb R$ that generates the normal topology, but for which all sets are bounded. "Closed & bounded $\implies$ compact" isn't always true for metric spaces. You cannot count on it except for $\Bbb R^n$ with the Euclidean metric. It is not even guaranteed for open subsets $\Omega$ of $\Bbb R^n$, as my first example shows.

Comment: Concerning your full question, what is the definition of $\hat K_\Omega$? I haven't been able to figure it out from the snippets you've included here. "Hull" would suggest the convex hull, but that doesn't seem to fully align with the comments being made, nor explain the dependence on $\Omega$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Dear Paul, i attached a print of the pages and put an rectangle over my doubts. I do not understand why hormander says that $\hat{K_{\Omega}}$ is compact and  Christine Laurent syas on her remark that it is not in general. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Check Hörmander carefully. Do they assume $\Omega$ is convex? If so, then the convex hull of $K$ is contained in $\Omega$ and is compact. Since in $\Omega, \hat K_\Omega$ is a closed subset of a compact set, it is compact itself. And as I said before, compact is compact, no matter the ambient space. On the other hand Laurent-Thiébaut is clearly not assuming $\Omega$ is convex.

Comment: $\Omega$ is just an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.